# Conditional Formatting help in excel (highlight certain row if a cell in a column displays #N/A)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to use conditional formatting to highlight a specific row of cells if a certain cell displays #N/A. I tried to use the function = isna() but it did not work as it only highlighted the first cell of the row that I was trying to highlight. What code could I use to make this work and then so that I could apply it to other subsequent rows as well?

Note: Using =ISNA($B3) applied to D3 and E3 will highlight, but when I try to the tab down to apply the formula to other rows. It changes the other rows to the text in D3 and E3. Any fixes?

[image: Conditional formatting help]

- In the image, I am trying to highlight D3-E3 since B3 shows #N/A
- I would also like for this to highlight all rows in which B shows #N/A

Answer (score 2):

If you enter `=ISNA($B3)` into the conditional format of cells D3 and E3 they will highlight if B3 shows an error.

You can extend this formula to other rows as well as the row index is not fixed to row 3 (but the column is fixed to column B).

Comment: Using =ISNA($B3) applied to D3 and E3 will highlight, but when I try to the tab down to apply the formula to other rows. It changes the other rows to the text in D3 and E3. Any fixes?

Comment: For row highlighting, you create a Conditional Format. This is where you enter the formula given, not in the cells! 1- in a row, select cells in columns A to E, 2- go to menu Format, Conditional Format, change to "formula is", enter "=ISNA($B3)" (if you are in row 3), choose a pattern for highlighting, Enter. To copy to other rows, use the "copy formats" button.